# ui.button opening modal dialog not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to show a modal dialog on button click, but
sometimes nothing happens until focus goes outside window, or it takes a few seconds till dialog is shown. What am I doing wrong?
I'm using jquery v1.11.2 and jquery-ui v1.11.3
here is the code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#myID1").button().click(function (e) {
        $('<div>test dialog</div>').dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            modal: true,
            title: '-- test --',
            buttons: {
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});


<body>
<button id="myID1" class="myClass">test1</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Its working fine check it http://jsfiddle.net/yr2fejnw/ @Johann

Comment: create a jsfiddle to show your problem

Comment: No, it's also not working in jsfiddle.net/yr2fejnw. Click it a few times and you see that button remains in clicked state and diaog only pops up when moving mouse outside window

Answer (score 0):

add any **Jquery library path** in your HTML code.
so that `ReferenceError: $ is not defined` error will be removed.

You can put below link inside `head` tag :
`<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script></head>`

### Demo :

[See Demo with Jquery reference](http://jsfiddle.net/yr2fejnw/)

Comment: hey @Johann, let me know if it works for you. by accepting it

Answer (score 0):

I tested some other browsers, and it only seems to be a 
problem with "Firefox ESR 31.5.0"